# can't access apache from localhost using xampp

Tags: xampp, localhost

Hi I am very new to programming. I am trying to access apache through localhost and I am using xampp. Everything is running, when I type in localhost and it does show "it works!", but when i enter localhost/~alexpham/ it shows not found! I have created a folder inside user. Any help would be great. I have tried everything.

cd /etc/apache2/users

Directory "/Users/alexpham/Sites/">

Options Indexes MultiViews

AllowOverride All

Require all granted

Allow from all

/Directory>

Alexs-MacBook-Pro:users Alexpham$ sudo chmod 644 alexpham.conf

Alexs-MacBook-Pro:users Alexpham$ sudo apachectl restart

Alexs-MacBook-Pro:users Alexpham$ cd ~/Sites/

Alexs-MacBook-Pro:Sites Alexpham$ open .

Alexs-MacBook-Pro:Sites Alexpham$ nano index.html

Comment: `~alexpham` would refer to a users home folder, for that you will need the user module to be enabled. Is that what you want? That is uncommon for development purposes. Those are usually directly worked on in the main document root, something like `/var/www/html` or similar.

Comment: Hi, I was watching this video on loading apache with mysql and php. this is what they showed and it seemed to work for them but doesn't seem to work for me. AlsoI'm not sure where i would put the /var/ www/ html .

Comment: The apache http server has a modular architecture, most of its features are implemented in loadable modules. One of those is the "user module" I referred to, correct would be "userdir module": https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html It maps incoming requests to paths starting with a tilde (`~`) to folders in server side user account home folders. That module has to be loaded in your http server, otherwise that won't work. So check that.

Comment: `/var/www/html` was just an example, the typical path used in Linux systems (Linux is the base for the vast majority of all web servers operated on this world). It is the central, default place configured as server side document root for the default http host published by a server. The path certainly might be different for you, take a look into your http servers host configuration for that. You want to look for "DOCUMENT_ROOT".

Comment: Thank you for you helping out. I will try to figure it out when i get home from work.